# Exception: EOF Serial port boost::asio::buffer

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've recently migrated from ROS indigo to ROS kinetic to find that I am getting some issues with running my ROS code on Kinetic, I know the response is due to an EOF read on the serial end but this can't be possible as I have checked the port and it is spitting out data from the minicom command, that and it worked perfectly fine in indigo.
Here is the suspect code that is captured in the exception

```
...
bool receive_next_packet(){
an_packet_t *an_packet;
int bytes_received;

if ((bytes_received = port_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(an_decoder_pointer(&an_decoder_), an_decoder_size(&an_decoder_)))) > 0) {
    /* increment the decode buffer length by the number of bytes received */
    an_decoder_increment(&an_decoder_, bytes_received);
...
```

and the exception entry is:
`[FATAL] [1493003769.565488812]: Exception thrown: read_some: End of file`

Also are there any good debuggers people can recommend for diagnosing this in an IDE?, Currently using Eclipse.
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit1: Further to this I have found that I am running a more recent release of libboost-dev-all, is this a bug with version 1.58? has anyone else encounter this same issue?
I will see if I can install 1.54 as it was on indigo.

Thanks in Advanced

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260041/exception:-eof-serial-port-boost::asio::buffer/) by [new2ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21455/new2ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well looks like the problem is the libboost-dev-all version 1.58 for 16.04
It is suggested that you downgrade to libboost-dev-all version 1.54 or other version as I dont see anything wrong with the code this should be a bug in 1.58.
Everything is working after the downgrade.

---

Originally posted by [new2ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21455/new2ros/) with karma: 50 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexisTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29858/alexistm/) on 2017-04-24**:
Also, avoid the version 1.53 and less which lacks some macros.